# Specified cast is not valid. error shows in window server 2008 r2

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, linq

I made a application in asp.net c# using linq and oracle database.This application is working fine on Widows 7 32 bit local host.But When I deployed this application in windows server 2008 r2.It gives a following error.Guide me what is the following error.How Can I check this error on deployment server and How can I resolved this error

> Specified cast is not valid. Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not
>   valid.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
>
> System.Data.UnboxT`1.ValueField(Object value) +54
>
> sis.<>c__DisplayClass55.b__0(DataRow r) +38
>
> System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +156
>
> System.Linq.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext() +165
>
> System.Linq.d__81`1.MoveNext() +472
>
> System.Linq.Enumerable.Count(IEnumerable`1 source) +267
>
> sis.regreport.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +5015
>
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>
> includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178

```
var vcolM = dt.AsEnumerable()
           .Where(r => r.Field<string>("MAJ") == (string)vprglist 
           && r.Field<string>("SPEC") == (string)vspecourse 
           && r.Field<string>("L_ABR_CODE") == (string)genderEng[1] 
           && r.Field<string>("reg") == (string)drRegion["reg"] 
           && r.Field<decimal>("year") == syrcnt)
           .Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r["strength"]));
```

All linq like above working fine in local pc.But giving error in windows server 2008.Where syrcnt is int.

Comment: put a breakpoint on the line, and examine exactly what type of object key is. When you know that, you will be in a better position to work out what kind of cast you need.

Comment: Because in deploymnet server How can I insert break point

Comment: Because in development server only DLLs files available.But in local pc application working fine

Comment: can you describe when this error occurs? I mean When you try to redirect to some page or at the very first time you try your url in the address bar ?

Comment: At the very first time.When I try url in the address bar

Comment: ok are you using some normal form that is using Master Page ? or its just a desktop app ?

Comment: It is a web based app.I am using normal form and No Master page.Only two pages.One is form and second is report

Comment: Are there any difference in column names of your Oracle db in your local machine vs the machine you deployed to? I suspect there's a mismatch.

Comment: working fine in local PC.But giving error in windows server 2008 r2

Comment: yes all field is Same

Comment: are you trying to cast any of the fields or the Enumerable in linq ?

Comment: Can you show us the Linq request?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of the `InvalidCastException` is the `r.Field<string>("MAJ") , r.Field<decimal>("year")` line. The `Field<T>` extension method will throw an `InvalidCastException` in the case where the actual type of the data doesn't match the type which was passed to `Field<T>`.

OR

lies in here `Convert.ToInt32(r["strength"])`, the strength might not be getting proper type

Honestly, I think you issues lies in the line `r.Field<decimal>("year")`. I may be wrong as there is not much information about the datatype of your variable `syrcnt`

Hence giving you the exception `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid`

Comment: syrcnt is int because I am using this is in for(int syrcnt =0;...)

Comment: is there any way to check error in deployment server